# How to make dual labeled axes from one dataset with d3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, axis, axis-labels

I'm trying to make a scatterpoint with dual labeled x-axes in d3 angular. I have my label-data on the format:

```
xlabels = [{PtName: "Name1", SocName: "Same soc!", Other: "Other1"},
           {PtName: "Name2", SocName: "Same soc!", Other: "Other2"},
           {PtName: "Name3", SocName: "Other soc", Other: "Other3"}];
ylabels = ["20%", "40%", "60%", "80%", "100%"]
```

And I want to have one x-axis showing PtName and another showing SocName. I'm trying with:

```
x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xlabels.map(function (d) { return {PtName: d.PtName, SocName: d.SocName}; }));
y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(ylabels);

xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').tickFormat(function(d, i) { return d.PtName; });
xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').tickFormat(function(d, i) { return d.SocName; });
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left');
```

But the tickFormat do not seem to work the way I indended. I get axes with only one value (the first): "Name1" and "Same sock!". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `.tickValues` instead to explicitly define axis tick values. Also, you might want to look into using `.rangeBands()` for ordinal scales (such as your PtName and SocName).

Comment: If I just replace tickFormat with tickValues in the code I get "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'PtName' of undefined or null reference". tickValues expects an array, right? How should I implement that?

Comment: I tried with `tickValues(xlabels.map(function (d, i) { return d.PtName; }))` but I get the same result: only the first value gets displayed.